# Rails - Truncate in a Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller, I'm building a json object for books. I want to show `truncate(book.content, 250)`.

This doesn't work in a rails controller. And given it's a JSON render, I don't use a view. So how does one truncate? I don't want my JSON object to be huge :)!

Comment: Very confusing. I want to build a JSON object with a text field but only show 250 chars... So I need to truncate. But Rails doesn't let you truncate in a View or Model, so where do I build the JSON object?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use many ways to accomplish this. The most conviniet one would be to just include the proper helper in the controller. In this it would be:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  ...
end
```

Alternatively you can also create a partial which generates the code you need, for example _truncate.html.erb with proper code:

```
<%= truncate (@book, :length => 250) %>
```

And then render it in your view:

```
result = render_to_string :partial => 'truncate'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing truncate(@book, 200) and that was erroring... When I used the :length it worked? Strange.. YOu don't need length in views..

Comment: truncate(@book, 200) syntax is deprecated for some time now, and the proper way to use truncate is to pass options hash after the object. I am not sure, why deprecated method worked in views and not in controller, but you should just stick to the new syntax. :-)

Answer (score 27):

You can just call the truncate rails string method.

http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate

```
"Once upon a time in a world far far away".truncate(27)

@book.content.truncate(250)
```

Not 100% sure if you have to include

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Comment: to me this is a better answer

Comment: This is a better answer because you don't have to include the helper.  It defaults to '...', but can pass omission: 'xxx' as an option.